# Transfer data from html-forms by mail in meteor.js

Tags: javascript, email, meteor, forms

How to transfer data from the html-forms in the body of the e-mail template in meteor.js? The documentation is an example:

`Meteor.call('sendEmail',
            'alice@example.com',
            'bob@example.com',
            'Hello from Meteor!',
            'This is a test of Email.send.');`

But it does convey only advance by string values. How to transfer data from the form?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
values = {
    nick: $('#nick').val(),
    message: $('#your-message').val()
}
```

and call method like

```
Meteor.call('sendEmail',
            'alice@example.com',
            'bob@example.com',
            'Hello from Meteor!',
            values);
```

And in method on server

```
Meteor.methods({
  sendEmail: function (to, from, subject, text) {

    Email.send({
      to: to,
      from: from,
      subject: subject,
      text: 'Hello '+text.nick+'. Your message was: '+text.message
    });
  }
});
```